# Creating shapes with while loop Python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, shapes

What I am trying to do is use a while loop to create a square out of asterixs, the code below will print the square filled in, but what I want it to do is print the square unfilled

```
a='square'
b='unfilled'
c=4
num=0
asterix='*'
while a=='square' and b=='unfilled' and int(num)<int(c):
    num+=1
    print(asterix*int(c))
```

What the code does:

```
****
****
****
****
```

What I want the code to do:

```
****
*  *
*  *
****
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    n = 4
    s = "*"
    for i in range(0,n,1):
        if i == 0 or i == n-1:
            print(s*n)
        else:
            print(s+(" "*(n-2))+s)
```

This should do what you want to. You don't have to convert everything correct.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was answered a long time ago, but I am going through some of my earlier class exercises too and trying to use some of the new things I have learned along the way.

This reminds me a lot of one of my exercises and I eventually answered it similar to the answer above. Since then I have discovered a nice way to write this using a generator:

```
n = 4
table = ("*  *" if i not in [0, n] else '****' for i in range(n+1))
for row in table: print(row)
```

You would probably want to generalise this too so that it worked for a variable size, `n`.